# How to update a number in the python shell without showing a list

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to make a number update itself in the shell so that it doesn't print the previous before it

e.g.

Button press 1

Button press 2

Button press 3

Button press 4

and so on

Is there a way of making it so it would just say "Button press" then say the number without showing a list above it?  I hope that makes sense.  I am doing a program that counts the times a button is pressed but I need it to say it once instead of making a big list in the shell.

Comment: You need to show us some of your code if you'd like us to be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. You have to adapt it to your code. This works for Python 3.0+.

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Now it is: ' + str(i), end='\r')
```

The trick is done by the end keyword which will return a pointer to the beginning of the line. However if you need to print other stuff in between, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

To print in shell call from shell:

```
import sys, time

for i in range(1,5):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('Button pressed: ' + str(i) +'\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```